# Not getting value in TextView

Tags: android, android-listview, gps, android-location

I am writing a program, in which i have to show calculated distance between two locations, from current location to destination location, and to get that i have written a method which calculates total distance between locations, now the main point is i am not getting distance value in TextView.

and here is my code, please check below:

**LocationsActivity.java:**

```
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(LocationsActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("locations");
                    Log.d("jarray", jarray.toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        locations = new Locations();

                        locations.setName(object.getString("name"));
                        locations.setLatitude(object.getString("latitude"));
                        locations.setLongitude(object.getString("longitude"));

                        actorsList.add(locations);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                //------------------>>

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


        public void distanceBetweenTwoLocations() {
        Location currentLocation = new Location("");
        currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);


        for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
            Location destinationLocation = new Location(" ");
            destinationLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLatitude()));
            destinationLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLongitude()));

            double inMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
            double totalDistance = inMeters / 1000;

            locations.setDistance(totalDistance + "");

           }            
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `locationList` is empty.

Comment: no i am getting data from JSON

Comment: But you are not adding it to the List.

Comment: are you getting value in `locationsList.get(position).getName()` ??

Comment: @SilentKiller i am getting values in a list, see doInBacground(...) from JSON, just not getting value for distance'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with your `distanceBetweenTwoLocations()` method.

you are adding location data in `actorsList` at doInBackground method while you are retrieving data from `locationsList`

Still same mistake with your getView method. you are adding data in `Locations` list while in getView you are fetching data from `locationsList`

**Updated :**

you are passing `actorsList` to the adapter while you are assigning distance to the `locations` list.

Check with Following Code :

you need to call the following method at `onPostExecute` before notifying adapter `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
public void distanceBetweenTwoLocations() {
    Location currentLocation = new Location("");
    currentLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    currentLocation.setLongitude(longitude);

    for (int i = 0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
        Locations mLocations = (Locations) actorList.get(i);
        Location destinationLocation = new Location(" ");
        destinationLocation.setLatitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLatitude()));
        destinationLocation.setLongitude(Double.valueOf(actorsList.get(i).getLongitude()));
        double inMeters = currentLocation.distanceTo(destinationLocation);
        double totalDistance = inMeters / 1000;
        mLocations.setDistance(totalDistance + "");
       }            
    }
}
```

Comment: @Moon are you getting data in `getView` .?

Comment: no that's not the mistake we can give any name to our ArrayList in Adapter class

Comment: this time i am not agree with you

Comment: @Moon [come here.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)